# Worauf kann sich ein Relativsatz beziehen, wenn man doppelten Genitiv hat?

Tags: grammar, genitive, relative-clause

> Sie ist beeindruckt von der Aula der Psychologie-Abteilung der Uni, die weltberühmt ist.

Kann sich "die weltberühmt ist" auf *der Aula*, *der Psychologie-Abteilung*, oder *der Uni* beziehen, oder sind alle drei möglich?

Comment: Völlig anderer Hinweis: _Abteilung_ paßt hier schlecht. Universitäten haben vielleicht eine Rechtsabteilung oder eine Planungsabteilung, aber die wissenschaftlichen Organisationseinheiten heißen _Fakultät_, _Institut_, _Seminar_ usw.; allerhöchstens haben die Institute noch einmal (sehr kleinteilige) Abteilungen.

Comment: @chirlu Okay, danke!

Comment: Du könntest schreiben: Sie ist beeindruckt von der Aula der Psychologie-Fakultät der weltberühmten Uni. Falls sich weltberühmt hier auf die Uni bezieht ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rein grammatikalisch kann sich "weltberühmt" in der Tat auf jeden dieser Genetive beziehen. Der Satz ist in der Tat nicht eindeutig; wenn sich die Meinung nicht aus dem Zusammenhang ergibt, sollte man ihn anders formulieren.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist im Sprachgebrauch nicht eindeutig.
Man kann den Relativsatz direkt hinter das Wort, auf das er sich beziehen soll, schreiben. Wenn es sich z. B. auf "Aula" beziehen soll, dann kann man

> Sie ist beeindruckt von der Aula, die weltberühmt ist, der Psychologie-Abteilung der Uni.

schreiben. Wenn er sich auf "Psychologie-Abteilung" oder "Uni" beziehen soll, kann man das nicht so umformulieren, dass es definitiv eindeutig wird. Wenn man (beispielsweise durch inhaltliche Kriterien) keinen Anhaltspunkt hat, worauf sich der Relativsatz beziehen soll, da er wie in deinem Beispiel ganz hinten im Satz steht, würde ich davon ausgehen, dass der Satz auf das Wort bezogen ist, hinter dem er unmittelbar steht, also in deinem Fall "Uni".

Comment: Ich würde vorschlagen den Relativsatz zugunsten eines einzelnen Adjektivs aufzulösen: von ... der weltberühmten Aula ... der weltberühmten Uni ... o. ä.

Comment: Mit dem Relativsatz nach _Aula_, wie oben, klingt der Rest für mich nach einer Apposition, d.h. als ob die Aula die Psychologie-Abteilung wäre.